# Search Column name in Linked Server (Oracle) from Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server

I need to retrieve Table Names from Linked Oracle Database which is on Linked Server with Microsoft SQL Server.

e.g. I can get table names in SQL Server using:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%TELEPHONE%'
```

but, I need Oracle Code. 
I am using Microsoft SQL Server with a linked server to Oracle.

Comment: You need Oracle code to do what? You what that query in oracle code?

Comment: Hi, SQL Query to retrieve Oracle Table Names

Comment: Sorted. Thanks. SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(ORACLE_DB_NAME,'SELECT table_name, column_name
FROM cols WHERE column_name LIKE ''%TELEPHONE%''')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
     * 
FROM 
     OPENQUERY(ORACLE_DB_NAME,'
          SELECT 
               table_name, 
               column_name 
          FROM 
               cols 
          WHERE 
               column_name LIKE ''%TELEPHONE%'''
      )
```

Based on your comment "**Hi, SQL Query to retrieve Oracle Table Names**", you can do the following:

```
SELECT 
     table_name, 
     column_name
FROM 
     cols
WHERE 
     column_name LIKE '%TELEPHONE%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `USER_TAB_COLS` or `ALL_TAB_COLS` view for it. Refer oracle documentation for more information on this views

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME 
FROM USER_TAB_COLS 
WHERE UPPER(COLUMN_NAME) LIKE '%TELEPHONE%';
```

`UPPER` is used in `WHERE` clause as names are case sensitive if they are created with double quotes and case insesitive if created with no quotes.

Cheers!!